# How to position a PNG image over a Basemap map?

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap, imshow, imread

I'm using a code to import an image from the ArcGIS server and use it as background figure. On that background I'm adding a rose of the winds, I import the rose of the winds with the function imread and I insert it using the imshow.

However, I do not know how to position it on the map. How can I put the center of the wind roses in the position I want? I also do not know how to set its size.

I'm using Basemap because it was the easiest way I found to insert a World Imagery as a background.

I researched other similar issues in the forum but none gave me a solution.

Below is the code I am using:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define the map boundaries lat/lon
top_right_lat = -13.68
top_right_lon = -48.16
bot_left_lat = -13.8
bot_left_lon = -48.32

# Create a Map object with cylindrical projection
m = Basemap(resolution='c',projection='cyl', \
            llcrnrlon=bot_left_lon, llcrnrlat=bot_left_lat, \
            urcrnrlon=top_right_lon, urcrnrlat=top_right_lat,)

## Add a ArcGIS background image.
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))

m.arcgisimage(service='World_Imagery', xpixels=1000, dpi=300, verbose=False)

meridians = np.arange(-48.3,-47.9,0.02)
m.drawmeridians(meridians,labels=[0,0,0,1],fontsize=14);

parallels = np.arange(-13.8,-13.68,0.02)
m.drawparallels(parallels,labels=[1,0,0,0],fontsize=14);

#Add the wind rose

datafile = 'WR_tarde.png'

im = plt.imread(datafile)

m.imshow(im, zorder=1, origin='upper', alpha=0.75)
```

Bellow is the figure I am getting:

[image]

The "origin" argument on the imshow function is used because the rose of the winds was with the axis and inverted.

With this code I can insert the wind rose but it is inserted in a fixed position, I do not know how to position it on the map.

I would like to know if there is anything I can do in my code that allows me to set the position of the roses in the winds, I would also like to set its size.

If anyone knows of another way to do this, I am open to suggestions.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Add this option `extent=(lonmin, lonmax, latmin, latmax)` to your `m.imshow()` statement. In `extent`, use the values in degrees that cover the intended location.

Comment: I had tried this, unfortunately it does not work. The added image always stays in the same position.

Comment: Instead of `m.imshow()`, try again with `ax.imshow()` with option `zorder=10`.